# How to specify generic trait in rust for generic struct

Tags: rust

This code:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct X<T: ?Sized> {
    a: T
}

trait BBB<Y> {
    fn boo(&self, y: Y);
}

impl<T, Y> BBB<Y> for X<T> where Y: Debug {
    fn boo(&self, y: Y) {
        println!("y={:?}", y);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: X<i32> = X { a: 3 };
    a.boo(a.a);
    a.boo("sd");
}
```

works fine.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to check the type of `Y` passed to `BBB::boo()`?
2. How to specify concrete type of `Y` for `BBB` trait in this code to avoid the opportunity to pass too many types in the `BBB::boo()` method?

Comment: Is your first question about runtime inspection of the type of `Y`?  Is your second question about restricting the types of `Y` that could be passed to the `boo` method?

Comment: Peter you are right. About first question it can be compile time check.

Comment: *"to avoid the opportunity to pass too many types"* - You cannot pass types that do not satisfy the trait bound requirements. A [where clause](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/where.html) is one way to express the bounds you intend to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to check the type of `Y` passed to `BBB::boo()`?

Sure, there are different ways in which you could implement a sort of type checking and tailor it to your needs. This can really depend on your specific requirements.

**TypeId**

The first one that comes to mind is to use [type id](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) which is just a globally unique identifier for any given type. You can compare the type id for one type against another to see if they are the same:

```
use std::any::{TypeId};

fn main() {
   let s = "Hello World!";
   let num = 3;

   # Returns a boolean based on whether the type id's are equal.
   let typeEquals = s.type_id() == num.type_id();

   println!("s == num ? {:#?}", typeEquals); // false
}
```

`TypeId` can be used for generics as well as concrete types. For instance, if you wanted to check if `Y` is a `String` in your `boo` function:

```
impl<T, Y> BBB<Y> for X<T> where Y: Debug {
   fn boo(&self, y: Y) {
      let is_string = TypeId::of::<String>() == TypeId::of::<Y>();
      println!("Y is string ? {:#?}", is_string);
   }
}
```

**Trait Bounds**

Another way is to use [trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) to restrict what types can be passed in for `Y`. In fact, you are already using a trait bound for `Y` in your `BBB<Y>` implementation for `X<T>` when you used `where Y: Debug`. You are essentially saying that `Y` must be a type that implements `Debug`.

As an example, if you wanted to make sure `Y` could be converted to a String you can use the [Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait as a trait bound on a generic type:

```
impl<T, Y> BBB<Y> for X<T> where Y: Into<String> {
    fn boo(&self, y: Y) {
        println!("{:#?}", y.into());
    }
}
```

The `Into<T>` trait requires that a type implement the `into` method and this method should convert the passed in type to the concrete type used for `T` in `Into<T>`. In the above example, `Y` is required to have an implementation for `Into<String>`. Sense this is a bound on `Y` we can use the `into` function to convert `Y` to a `String` even if we don't know the type of `Y` beforehand.

> How to specify concrete type of `Y` for `BBB` trait in this code to avoid the 
>   opportunity to pass too many types in the `BBB::boo()` method?

This done by replacing your generic `Y` with a concrete type in your implementation of the trait. This could be considered another way of restricting your trait to specific types as well. Here is a impl of you `BBB<Y>` trait that specifies a `String` as the concrete type:

```
impl<T> BBB<String> for X<T> {
    fn boo(&self, y: String) {
        println!("string={:#?}", y);
    }
}
```

The above implementation replaces the generic `Y` with a the concrete `String` type in two places. The first being your actual trait name `BBB<String>` and the second is where `Y` is the parameter in your `boo` method. This doesn't mean that your trait is restricted to only using a String though. While restricting your trait to one type is a possibility, you could also create implementations for other types as well. For instance, you could use `i32`:

```
impl<T> BBB<i32> for X<T> {
    fn boo(&self, y: i32) {
        println!("i32={:#?}", y);
    }
 }
```

Different implementations for types provides greater flexibility when you need different functionality based on what type is passed in.

Comment: Thank for your answer! But is it possible to modify only main function to prevent the opportunity call `boo()` for different types?

Comment: No problem at all :) Um the main function is usually set in stone and doesn't change except for cases like Futures/Async. You would just want to create a different function for any thing like that.